# Command not found when sshing into Ubuntu for amazon instance

Tags: ssh

When trying to ssh into my ubuntu instance, I receive `-bash: ssh: command not found`. I'm trying to connect to an instance on amazonaws. Im running cygwin off of windows 7

Comment: good question ... issue also happens when attempting to ssh out from a Ubuntu docker container which for efficiency does not include ssh client

Answer (score 11):

Is ssh installed?

`sudo apt-get install openssh-client`

It is saying that you do not have ssh.

**UPDATE:**

If on cygwin [(look here)](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/tools/benchmarks/browse/doc/cygwin.html):

```
cd /to/where/cygwin/is
setup-x86.exe -q -P openssh
```

Or if its 64bit:

```
cd C:\Cygwin
setup-x86_64.exe -q -P openssh
```

You may have to run it as administrator or try reinstalling cygwin and make sure the little ssh box is checked.

Comment: Im running cygwin off of windows 7

Comment: Please include this information in your question.

Comment: Did not see the ssh box in the installation box. I re downloaded cygwin with all default settings.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to the cygwin directory and trying the above commands in CMD? Also, This might be off topic and may find better support in a different forum.

Comment: Im using the setup kernel now. Everything seems to be getting the same response: command not found. Thank you!

Comment: Does setup.exe exist in the cygwin directory `C:/Cygwin`? And when you run `setup.exe -q -P openssh` in command prompt does it still happen?

Comment: -bash: ssh-host-config: command not found. Just to be clear am I literally typing setup.exe -q -P openssh or are there breaks in there. setup.exe is in the cygdrive

Comment: It may be something like `setup-x86.exe -q -P openssh`